# GET response is not being rendered in React Container

Tags: reactjs, rendering

Following is my container code. I am pulling posts from WordPress blog.

I am getting correct console log in console, but for some reason this part `{this.props.posts.map(this.renderPosts)}` in container is not being rendered properly, it's only rendering blank `P` element.

How can I figure out the issue?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchPosts} from '../../action/index';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class Blog extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }
   renderPosts(postData){               
      return Object.keys(postData.posts).map(id => {
        return (
                <div id={postData.posts[id].site_ID}>{postData.posts[id].title}</div>
        ); 
    });
}
    render(){
        console.log('Posts are: ',this.props.posts);
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/posts/new"><button> Add a New Post </button> </Link>  
                <p>
                    {this.props.posts.map(this.renderPosts)}
                </p>  
            </div>
        );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        posts: state.posts
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({fetchPosts}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Blog);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
renderPosts(postData){               
   return Object.keys(postData.posts).map(id => {
        console.log('pd', postData.posts[id]);
        return (
            <tr>
                <p>{postData.posts[id].title}</p>
            </tr>
        ); 
    });
}
```

You're missing a return in renderPosts()

Comment: Thank you very much @viljar

Comment: Hi @Viljar, I just updated code for renderPosts function and I have assigned key also, but I am still getting warning for not having key for children in array? Any idea? Thanks